# type of store state not working with modules

Tags: typescript, type-inference, vuex-modules, vuex4

I want to use modules for a vuex (^4.0.2) store that should work with typescript. So I just started to out like that:

```
import {createStore, Module} from 'vuex';


type RootState = {
  appID: string
}

type SessionState = {
  lastSeen: number
}

const session: Module<SessionState, RootState> = {
  state: () => ({ lastSeen: -Infinity })
}

const store = createStore<RootState>({
  state: () => ({appID: 'r2d2'}),
  modules: {
    session
  }
});

const s2 = store.state.session;
```

But that yields this error:

> Property 'session' does not exist on type 'RootState'.

The [docs](https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html) suggest that the state of each module is included within the state of the store and using this:

```
//@ts-ignore
console.log(store.state.session)
```

show that the module is included.

*How should types be setup to properly reflect the state?*

Comment: Plese share reproducable example. I dod knot where did you get `createStore`, `Module` ..

Comment: are you sure `createStore` is imported like that?

Comment: yes. like that (from running code): `import { createStore } from "vuex";` What's wrng with that? Notice that it is vuex version 4

Comment: This is what I'm getting in ts playground `Module '"vuex"' has no exported member 'createStore'. Did you mean to use 'import createStore from "vuex"' instead?`

Comment: No. I am using it as stated above. Could you share the playground link?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwMZQKYEMaoMo2qgGjgFkIATAVwBtUBfOAMyghDgHIA3C1ADzYG4AUMJgBPMKjgAlCBBi5MkgLyJBcOOjBgAkgBEAXHADOMKMAB2Ac0G0R4ydlRGjwCOYVY4KhGrhV0Jo6o5obmFCAARqhQNsJIbibGTi5uhqSUNAA8js6u7jCKRDJyHqgAfF6q6iaKhgAUAJReFXUIfgHyqMGGALTa5gwWwGJwtA2xgvHmiSb4lSgYWLj4mcXyBVhlrb41WPVNSi0ImjoG7FAATGQXbGMEviDk1E6GPurVyXm+tmNCkwnwIwXSqzNAAOl2qAhnzc-CAA

Answer (score 0):

The only "solution" I found to get typing :

```
import {createStore, Module} from 'vuex';

type SessionState = {
  lastSeen: number;
}

type RootState = {
  appID: string;
  session?: SessionState; // added here
}

const session: Module<SessionState, RootState> = {
  state: () => ({ lastSeen: -Infinity })
}

const store = createStore<RootState>({
  state: () => ({appID: 'r2d2'}),
  modules: {
    session
  }
});

const s2 = store.state.session; // typed as SessionState
```

It works but it is pretty inconvenient, and weird...
I didn't found any other though. (I searched a lot...)
Any better solution is welcome

edit:
I think this issue might be helpful :
https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1689

edit2:

Well previous link was not really usefull.
I found a better solution than the code above:

- https://qdmana.com/2021/09/20210914103352881Q.html

edit3 :
Well edit 2, not that great.

- https://github.com/vuejs/vuex/issues/1831